# Spring Tool Suite (STS) on Ubuntu 16.04 becomes unresponsive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, spring-tool-suite

In an empty workspace, I right-click package explorer and select Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Project. Then, when I click the next button, a spinner starts spinning and never returns, just continues hanging. Is there anything I can do to debug this issue?

Also, if I go into preferences and start clicking around, the preferences pane never refreshes with content for the new selection.

I've never had these problems before but this is the first time I've used STS since upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04. Would it help to wipe the OS and reinstall?

I've tried removing STS and reinstalling newer and older versions with the same problems each time.

Comment: maybe you are running into issues with the GTK3 support on Ubuntu. Try to set the environment variable SWT_GTK3=0. Maybe that helps. If not, I would recommend to capture a thread dump of the process (using jps and jstack) to see what is hanging under the hood.

Comment: Before I saw your reply, I went ahead and reinstalled the OS. The problem was still here. Then, I went ahead and set that environment variable and that seems to have solved it. Thanks.